# in C#, a method who gives me a list of months and year between two dates

Tags: c#

please can you help me with this method.
I want to have the list of months and years between a date and the current month.
For example, from 23 october 2016 the result is:
October 2016
November 2016
December 2016
January 2017
February 2017
March 2017
April 2017
May 2017

Very thanks, Dia

Comment: What have you tried?  hint:  There is an `AddMonths()` method, and `DateTime` objects are comparable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will do it. What it returns is a series of dates - the first day of each month which is part of the range.

```
public IEnumerable<DateTime> GetMonths(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    if(startDate > endDate) 
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            $"{nameof(startDate)} cannot be after {nameof(endDate)}");
    }
    startDate = new DateTime(startDate.Year, startDate.Month, 1);
    while (startDate <= endDate)
    {
        yield return startDate;
        startDate = startDate.AddMonths(1);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var months = GetMonths(startDate, endDate);
```

For example, if the the parameters are February 7, 2016 and April 2, 2016, it will return
February 1, 2016
March 1, 2016
April 1, 2016